# Did Dr. Pulaski leave Star Trek Next Generation due to her pushing Troi away from Riker in her last episode?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In Season 2, Episode 22, "Shades of Gray", Dr. Pulaski pushed Deanna Troi's hand away from Riker when she was trying to give him a final treatment to rid his body of the infection from a vine that had infected him? Was this the reason why the character left the show?

It appeared so quickly so I looked at it again and that is what I saw. It appeared to be an out of place action by Diana Muldaur. When I watched the next episode, Pulaski was no longer on ST:TNG and Dr. Beverly Crusher was in the next and following episodes from then on.

Comment: I don't see an actual question here. This looks like you're trying to start a conversation about this scene, which is not the purpose of this site.

Comment: I see Pulaski doing that at about 43:00 in the episode, but that was because Deanna's hand was in the way as Pulaski wanted to give Riker an hypospray of some medication in the arm.

Comment: If the implication of your question is 'did this apparently out of character action result in her termination' - the answer is 'no'. Muldaur is listed as a 'Special Guest Star' during the entire season. McFadden was unhappy w/ Season 1 and left and Muldaur was only planned to be a single season character.

Comment: @Sava Yes.  It appeared so.  But, it looked bad.  Why didn't they just reshoot it so it didn't appear like Pulaski was being pushy?

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  That makes sense now.

Comment: Because Pulaski was pushy.

Comment: Pulaski = pushy is pretty much her entire character

Comment: Yes, that's the impression that I got, too.

Comment: Just to clarify - with your edit, are you asking if that had something to do with the *actress*' departure (out of universe), or the *character*'s departure (in-universe)?

Comment: “Why didn't they just reshoot it so it didn't appear like Pulaski was being pushy?” Spending more time and money to improve quality was probably not something the production team considered at any point while making this episode.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Portal:Main) article on [Doctor Pulaski](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Katherine_Pulaski), the fact that the character left the show was a sort of mutual agreement between the staff, the producers and the actress portraying Pulaski:

> The Pulaski character was ultimately deemed to have been a failed experiment. Rick Berman commented, "That never quite worked [....] The character of Doctor Pulaski just never really quite solidified." Not only did the TNG staffers turn down the offer of renewing Diana Muldaur's contract for TNG Season 3 but Muldaur herself wasn't really interested in reprising the role of Pulaski either, as she had found that the mythos of TNG was such a technology-based setting with little focus, compared to TOS, on character. (William Shatner Presents: Chaos on the Bridge)

Thus her leaving the show wasn't specifically linked to that tiny gesture.